# JMock and Scala - unexpected invocation error

Tags: scala, junit, mocking, jmock

I'm new to JMock and trying to get a simple unit test working through Scala. The test is mocking an interface and then setting some xpectations before executing a method on the mocked interface.

```
 val context = new Mockery
 val mockObj= context.mock(classOf[SomeClassInterface])

 @Test def sometest = {
 context.checking(
      new Expectations() {
        allowing (mockObj).doFunc1(); 
        will(returnValue(someResponse);
        allowing (mockObj).doFunc2(someResponse); 
        will(returnValue(someResponse));
        allowing (mockObj).doFunc3(someResponse); 
        will(returnValue("Enabled"));
       }
 )
 var status:String = mockObj.doSomething()
 //context.assertIsSatisfied();
 Assert.assertTrue(status.equalsIgnoreCase("Enabled"))
```

}

This results in the error;

> unexpected invocation; mockObj.doSomething() ......... what happened before this; nothing!

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: Your expectations do not allow the `doSomething` method to be called. They only allow `doFunc1`, `doFunc2` and `doFunc3` to be called on the `mockObj` (and you do not call these methods at all, so why allow them?).

Comment: i thought the idea was to only set expectations on methods which might be called as a byproduct of calling doSomething. In my case whenever a call to doSomething happens it then causes the doFunc1 2 & 3 methods to be called

Comment: Causes how? You say that `SomeClassInterface` is an interface, so there is no implementation of `doSomething`. Anyway even if there is an implementation, the whole idea of creating a mock object is to not use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about Scala, but are you missing the double '{{' '}}' syntax? We're very sorry about it, but it's the best we could do in Java.

The outer '{}' is an anonymous subclass, and the inner '{}' is an initialisation block.